# Magento 2 Cart Price Rules for Grouped Product

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I need to create a cart price rule that will apply to a customers basket when they add a grouped product. We sell 'boxes' of items as a grouped product and want to add a free item to the order for certain boxes.

Is there a way to achieve that either as standard or by modifying Magento? I tried adding a rule based on the SKU of the grouped product but that doesn't seem to be supported?

Comment: when the customer adds the item to their basket they are adding the simple product that is part of the grouped product. You can't use grouped product SKUs in cart rules. You could create an attribute for each of those simples and use that attribute in the rule

Comment: @jscar the problem with that is how do I limit it so the basket needs to have ALL the items in it from the grouped product and not trigger off just one?